# python function does not work in Tensorflow: tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

my function is :

```
def groupl1(x):
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.sqrt(tf.to_float(x.get_shape()[1])) * tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(x ** 2, axis=1)))
```

and when i put it in my code:

```
elif loss == 'rmse,gl':
weightss=tf.trainable_variables()
reg=tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(groupl1,weightss)
loss =  tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(x_, decoded)))
                        )+reg*0.0001
```

it doesn't work with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "L1_02.py", line 45, in <module>
train_X_=model.fit_transform(train_X)
File "/home/hjson/tmp/BRCA/libsdae/stacked_autoencoder.py", line 93, in fit_transform
self.fit(x)
File "/home/hjson/tmp/BRCA/libsdae/stacked_autoencoder.py", line 70, in fit
print_step=self.print_step, lambda_=self.lambda_)
File "/home/hjson/tmp/BRCA/libsdae/stacked_autoencoder.py", line 138, in run
reg=tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(groupl1,weightss)
NameError: global name 'groupl1' is not defined
```

I'm confused because I clearly stated groupl1 function in my code. 
What is my problem here?

Comment: Where is groupl1 defined in relation to where it is used?

Comment: Also, I see from the stack trace that the code runs in some tmp folder. Make sure that `groupl1` is **globally available** when you run your code, e.g. add the path/to/the/script that has `groupl1` defined  to the Path.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing do you **define your function before you call it**?

```
def groupl1(x):
    return ...

.
.
.

groupl1(example_input)
```

Comment: Yes I defined my function before. And I figured out what my problem was. I defined the function in a class and I tried to use the function in the same class. I fixed it, and it worked well. thanks for your time.

Comment: Also the first argument in tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization() needs to be a function without its value

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe you want to add an answer with your solution for others coming with the same problem. And accept an answer so the question is marked as answered.